# pq: duplicate key value violates unique constraint \"pg_type_typname_nsp_index\"

Tags: postgresql, go

I am trying to run some postgres sql 11 migrations which involves creation of tables if it doesn't exist inside of a docker container using goose of golang.

Below is the sql script

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS identity.mytable (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    name text,
    CONSTRAINT mytable_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

I am sure that the table is not being manipulated by any other process except this so not sure why I get this error.

```
pq: duplicate key value violates unique constraint \"pg_type_typname_nsp_index\"
```

is it possible that the schema name, I am trying to use is `identity` which is a reserved keyword?

Comment: Guarantee safety from what? The error message would be a sign of safety in operation. It is an unusual message though - can you [edit] your question and describe what exactly you did to get it? Also, let us know what unsafe behavior you are afraid of.

Comment: If that `CREATE TABLE` causes the error, that would be bad. It would have to be `relation "..." already exists`. That low-level error message makes me afraid that you may have a corrupted database. Did you mess with catalog tables? I'd get a consultant to look at it.